# WSO2 ESB > Message Processor > Continuous operation Message Processor

Tags: wso2, max, continuous

When the backend is down, I would like to keep the Message Processor always active without having to drop any pending message and without having the necessity of reactivating the Message Processor manually.

I have three suggestions to solve. I think from better to worse. Can you send an example?

1. Use some kind of Quartz configuration file path to keep the Message Processor active always.
2. Could you give value '-1' to the max.delivery.attempts parameter to get a continuous execution of the message processor?
3. Set parameter max.delivery.attempts with a very large number.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set max.delivery.attempts to -1, give a value (in ms) to client.retry.interval and your forwarding message processor will never be deactivated

Comment: Hi @Jean-Michel unfortunatelly I have this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990476/wso2-esb-message-processor-max-delivery-attempts-always-return-to-its-defaul  thanks