# WSO2 ESB > Message Processor > max.delivery.attempts always return to its default value of 4?

Tags: wso2, message, processor

When I change the value of `max.delivery.attempts` parameter in the WSO2 message processor and save changes. It always return to its default value of 4.

I can change the value of other parameters without problem.

My configuration is:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- wso2 6.1.1
- mysql 5
- jdk 1.8.0_131

Does it happen to you?

Thanks

Comment: It does not happen to us. Stackoverflow is not the place to report bugs if you have any. You need to use wso2 issue reporting means.

Comment: its working fine.. lookout for anyother typo in the sequence

Comment: Sorry I changed value from design view with same issue and I have same problem changing value in code view . example <parameter name="max.delivery.attemps">7</parameter>

Answer (score 1):

Kindly Himasha notice me that it will be solved in next version

https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/1609